# Logout using session.invalidate(), does not forward to login page thereafter

Tags: jsf, session, redirect, prettyfaces

I have a logout link which looks like:

```
    <h:form>
       <div>
         <h:commandButton value="Logout" action="#{Bean.logOut}" />
       </div>
    </h:form>
```

And the corresponding logout method:

```
 public String logOut()throws Exception{
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        httpSession.invalidate();
        return "pretty:index?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

when i click on logout button it's working fine but seams when i'm trying to forward login page it's doesn't working and i got error like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:483)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
at com.test.Bean.onErrorHome(Bean.java:262)
at com.test.Bean.<init>(Bean.java:51)
at com.test.service.BeanList.<init>(BeanList.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:94)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:82)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:176)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.util.FacesElUtils.getExpectedType(FacesElUtils.java:50)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.beans.ParameterInjector.injectQueryParams(ParameterInjector.java:125)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.beans.ParameterInjector.injectParameters(ParameterInjector.java:55)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.PrettyPhaseListener.afterPhase(PrettyPhaseListener.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

*How can i solving this problem .
Please help me .
Thanks in advance .*

Comment: I have encountered a very similar behaviour; worked around it then. Could you tell which Java EE server you are using, Java 7?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017487/redirect-after-logout-fails-with-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-create) should be useful.. Just check the scope of the beans as discussed in the link I have pointed out..

Comment: JBoss with me, which is tomcat too.

Comment: @JoopEggen tomcat 7 .

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, so that we can see who's calling `sendRedirect()` at the wrong moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the stack trace who's calling the `sendRedirect` at the wrong moment:

```
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
at com.test.Bean.onErrorHome(Bean.java:262)
at com.test.Bean.<init>(Bean.java:51)
at com.test.service.BeanList.<init>(BeanList.java:84)
```

The page which you're redirecting to after logout is apparently referencing `BeanList` in whose constructor another `Bean` instance is manually been constructed in whose constructor `onErrorHome()` method is been invoked which is calling `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`.

I'm not sure what you're all doing there, but given this problem it's definitely not done right. You're basically attempting to redirect while the page is busy generating HTML output. A part of that HTML has already been sent to the webbrowser (i.e. the response is already committed).

You've 2 options:

1. Move that logic to a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).
2. Perform the `onErrorHome()` job during `preRenderView` event instead of in constructor.

   ```
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{beanList.init}" />
   ```

   This method is invoked **before** JSF starts rendering/generating/sending HTML output, so you've all freedom to change the response to a different destination without risking `IllegalStateException: response already committed` errors.

#### See also:

- [Redirect before loading the page in JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598375/redirect-before-loading-the-page-in-jsf2/)
- [Jsf2.0 forwarding page error without parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784351/jsf2-0-forwarding-page-error-without-parameter/)
- [Is there any easy way to preprocess and redirect GET requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294651/is-there-any-easy-way-to-preprocess-and-redirect-get-requests/)

Comment: thanks BalusC 
your answer almost help to me .
and i got my correct problem ,solved it .

Answer (score -1):

At end of function you can call getSession again with true value for re create the session.

```
     public String logOut()throws Exception{
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            httpSession.invalidate();
            return "pretty:index?faces-redirect=true";
            httpSession = (HttpSession)facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
            return "pretty:index?faces-redirect=true";
        }
```